# Can't make my android app post to a friend's facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook

I have made a nameday app. The app knows what names celebrate each day, and notifies the user.
I had connected the app to fb quite a long time ago, but with all the sdk changes, the code I used then doesn't work now and crashes the app.

I had the following then:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message",postmessage.getText().toString());
mFacebook.request("/"+id+"/feed",parameters,"POST");
```

the id is the friend's id. The message passed into the parameters is taken from the user from an edittext box.

Which is the correct and simplest way to do this now? Tried something like:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message",postmessage.getText().toString());
parameters.putString("to",id);

mFacebook.dialog(ActionFB.this, "feed", parameters, new DialogListener() {

@Override
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onError(DialogError e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
```

but the popup says that i passed bad parameters to the dialog.

Comment: you're posting on a friend's wall, as far as I understand from your code. Facebook disabled that feature, to prevent spam. See https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Comment: Thanx a lot tattvamasi, somehow somehow between all the outdated posts on facebook sdk, I missed that change. Seems that I have to change to a Share Dialog in order to make the app post to others' walls.

Comment: yup. I know, Facebook is a disaster recently.